# What's wrong with this "HTTP.Get" in SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, activities

In activities I am running this script:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1")
var NewReq = HTTP.Get("http://samplesite.com/sample.html");
</script>
```

It always throws errors.
It is calling a cloud page with ampscript, which separately works like intended if loaded manually:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET","POST");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
</script>
%%[
var @now
set @now = Now()
var @rowCount, @rows, @row, @signupdate
set @rows = LookupRows('trigger_DE','Count', '1')
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
set @row = row(@rows,@i)
set @signupdate = field(@row,"last_activity_time")
set @expireTime = DateAdd(@signupdate, '10','MI')
if @now > @expireTime then
DeleteData('trigger_DE','last_activity_time',@signupdate)
endif
next @i
endif
]%%  
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So why doesn't the script that calls the cloudpage work?

Comment: can you share the errors you are getting?  Also, I would check out this answer as Cloudpages require some accepted encoding in the GET to properly display (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158442/using-ampscript-to-retrieve-content-from-cloudpages/194703#194703)

Comment: The error email I get just says, "check more info in the activity tag in the automation# but there it says nothing more than "Error occured".

Comment: try putting it into a microsite or cloudpage with the try/catch function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to receive a more detailed error.  Also it seems you are using the Core library GET without declaring the core library `Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");`
 - I would either declare the library or use SSJS Platform version of Get (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPGet.htm)