# CloudPage UTF-8 encoding issue - SSJS / AMP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage, character-encoding

While creating cloud pages I would like to debug the pages and don't want to wait every time somewhere between 5 and 15 minutes for the page to be re-published.

That's the reason why we are using a solution where we can collect an entire HTML file from an online drive. In this case, I'm using Google Drive.

The AMPscript in the CloudPage;

```
%%=treatascontent(HTTPGet("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=[FILE_ID]"))=%%
```

This works perfectly fine, except the document in google does contain some special characters. If i'm opening the google document via Postman i do receive the html contents with the expecting UTF-8 encoding format.
But when I try to display the contents in the CloudPage via the TreatAsContent method it will convert my special characters into something which is unreadable. Which is causing the page to break down.

```regex
# Expected value (valid regex)
/^([a-zA-ZÀ-ǿ]\.)+$/

# Received value ( invalid regex )
/^([a-zA-ZÃ€-Ç¿]\.)+$/
```

Whenever I paste the entire HTML which is in the Google file it works fine without any encoding issues.

The following steps I've already tried without any luck;

```js
<script runat="server">
    HTTPHeader.SetValue('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    HTTPHeader.SetValue('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8');
</script>
```

and this one;

```js
<script runat="server">
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
req.contentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
req.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
req.method = "GET";
  
var response = req.send();
Variable.SetValue('content', String(response.content));
</script>

%%=v(@content)=%%
```

And i've also tried this one;

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222514/42522

The HTML of the file does contain the meta charset, so I guess it should be processed how I expect it to be.

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Does anyone know if it's possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Why use Google drive..... this this similar approach using Github... easy to setup in few steps..... great detailed guide here https://www.marketingdeveloper.io/blog/develop-sfmc-cloudpages-using-github-private-repositories by Susane Antunes

Comment: Well Google Drive is live sync, and if we would configure it to work via Github then every tiny adjustment would lead to a ton of commits. So yes, it might be something. But the Google Drive would still be the most ideal pick for my situation.